# Errors when implementing a fwrite to get date from socket

Tags: c, sockets

I see a plenty of examples but none addresses what I want to accomplish. I need to read the bytes from a socket and write them in to a file. In this [Code Project blog](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/586000/Networking-and-Socket-programming-tutorial-in-C) I see where in the client script a while loop iterates through a read call:

```
while((n = read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1)) > 0)
```

So I modified the code do that `fputs(recvBuff, f1)` where `f1` is a pointer to a pdf file. A pdf file is also a file I'm fetching from the server so I need to reassemble it, however the fputs operated with a string and corrupts the file, so I need a byte "writer" so fwrite would have been the choice but I can't get fwrite to work. I ended up modifying my code to resemble some of the examples to test it out but to no avail.

If in fwrite the first parameters is the 'data' how would I pass it? I've tried the read() call as in the while loop above but that seem to return an integer rather then a byte stream. Any ideas?

I'm new to programming but am new to C and would appreciate a little push in a right direction. Thanks.

Comment: fputs expects a null-byte terminated string. Use fwrite instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something more like this.  `fwrite` doesn't return a stream it returns the number of items (i.e. the 3rd parameter) successfully written.  In this case the "item" is a single char and you are attempting to write "bytesRead" number of them.  Good form dictates that you should check that the result `fread` returns is the same as you requested be written but this rarely fails on a disk file so many people skip it in non-critical situations.  You may want to add that on yourself.

```
FILE *f1;
 int  sockfd;
char recvBuff[4096];

size_t  bytesWritten;
ssize_t bytesRead;

while((bytesRead = read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff))) > 0)
    bytesWritten = fwrite(recvBuff, 1, bytesRead, f1);
```

Comment: Thanks for a simple yet eloquent explanation!

Comment: You are welcome.  The buffer should have been `unsigned char` but in this case it won't make any difference.